# configure: WARNING: *** Please install the SQLite3 development package

Tags: 10.04, asterisk

I am trying to install Asterisk on my ubuntu system.I have sucessfully downloaded asterisk package and when i tried to build and install it using

```
./configure
```

its showing an error

```
configure: WARNING: *** Asterisk now uses SQLite3 for the internal Asterisk database.
configure: WARNING: *** Please install the SQLite3 development package.
```

then i installed the sqlite using the following command

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite //also tried the following
 sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

After installing sqlite i am still getting same error while running `./configure`

```
 configure: WARNING: *** Asterisk now uses SQLite3 for the internal Asterisk database.
 configure: WARNING: *** Please install the SQLite3 development package.
```

Can anyone help!

Thanks

Comment: typically development packages in ubuntu end with `-dev`.

Answer (score 21):

After searching a lot i got it fixed.Used the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Got it from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=302790) forum.